# Ubuntu 22.04 host Windows 10 guest VIrtual Box 6.1: Drag and Drop not working, usb flash drive not being detected, how to solve?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, windows-10, drag-and-drop

I just installed Virtual Box 6.1 on my laptop, I have Ubuntu 22.04 as host and Windows 10 as guest and I just cannot share files beetwen host and guest.
I already looked into loads of tutorials online but VM just wont detect my usb and drag and drop does not work either.
Has anybody solved any of those problems?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you install the extension pack? How did you install VB?

Comment: Yes I did install it. I installed downloading from the website and it didn't work then I installed it using the command line but it didn't make any difference, I still cannot use my usb neither drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack`.

If you installed VirtualBox using `apt`, then run

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-ext-pack
```

If you installed VirtualBox from Oracle site, you can download it from there too.

Comment: I have already installed the extension pack and still not being able to detect the USB neither to use drag and drop.

Comment: I read an article saying that windows 10 won't  USB 3.0.

Comment: Did you enable Drag & Drop in the machine menu? Also you have to enable USB devices too, or set them up permanently.

Comment: Yes I did enable drag and drop. I did enable the USB devices, but for some reason it just won't detect my usb on the filter section.

Comment: It works for me on Ubuntu 20.04 with W10 guest.

Comment: Try to install VB from the Oracle site.